# Embedded PDF viewer with scrolling events

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, scroll

I'm working on a subscription project and I've come across an issue I can't seem to solve by myself.

The last subscription step requires user to fully read a PDF report before they can go on. 
Therefore I'm looking for a PDF viewer that can provide information about current scroll position.

I've tried using `<iframe>`, `<embed>` and `<object>`. But none of them seem to be able to handle such an event.

So basically, all I need is an HTML PDF viewer that "shares" enough information, so I can check whether scrolling position reaches the document bottom or not.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question :

I've found a pretty useful tool called PDF.js
For those looking for the same kind of feature, here's the link :
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Cheers!

Comment: PDF.js is built-in in Firefox. Whenever you view a PDF in Firefox, that is PDF.js under the hood.